# mssql 2008 datediff with minutes

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am using this :

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '08:00:00.000';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '08:04:21.000'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @enddate) as minute;
```

and i get output 
minute : 4

but when i input below:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2 = '08:00:00.000';
DECLARE @enddate datetime2 = '07:59:21.000'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @enddate) as minute;
```

then i get output : -1

so i dont want output : -1  . it must be blank as output

Thank you

Comment: "Please help me...its urgent..." - incorrect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to apply logic such as `if @startdate is greater than @enddate then null else datediff`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @startdate > @endate THEN NULL 
       ELSE DATEDIFF(minute, @startdate, @endate) END
```